# PHP on IIS 7.5 and MS-SQL Connection error

Tags: php, windows, iis-7.5

I'm trying to connect MS-SQL DB in PHP application.
there are web-server and db-server, webserver is using IIS 7.5 and I've added PHP 5.3.28 for running php application and dbserver has a MS-SQL and My-SQL.

I've downloaded "Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server" and installed on Web Server and added `extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll` on `php.ini`

I still can not connect to ms-sql
- error message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_min_message_severity() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\******\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mssql.php on line 123
```

which means, I can not connect ms-sql.

what else I'm missing here..??

Any comments would be appreciated.!

Comment: did you get the right version of the drivers? there's usually two versions of php floating around for windows: thread-safe and non-thread safe. You've got the TS version (thread-safe), which won't work with a non-thread-safe php.

Comment: In Php version information, Thread Safety is enabled. I also used php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll (Thread Safe)  component.  For IIS 7.5 and MS-SQL, I can use TS as well right..?